# Fetching distinct values on a column using Spark DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.6.1 version I need to fetch distinct values on a column and then perform some specific transformation on top of it. The column contains more than 50 million records and can grow larger.
I understand that doing a `distinct.collect()` will bring the call back to the driver program. Currently I am performing this task as below, is there a better approach?

```
 import sqlContext.implicits._
 preProcessedData.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)

 preProcessedData.select(ApplicationId).distinct.collect().foreach(x => {
   val applicationId = x.getAs[String](ApplicationId)
   val selectedApplicationData = preProcessedData.filter($"$ApplicationId" === applicationId)
   // DO SOME TASK PER applicationId
 })

 preProcessedData.unpersist()
```

Answer (score 71):

Well to obtain all different values in a `Dataframe` you can use [distinct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame). As you can see in the documentation that method returns another `DataFrame`. After that you can create a `UDF` in order to *transform* each record.

For example:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 6))).toDF("age", "salary")

// I obtain all different values. If you show you must see only {1, 3}
val distinctValuesDF = df.select(df("age")).distinct

// Define your udf. In this case I defined a simple function, but they can get complicated.
val myTransformationUDF = udf(value => value / 10)

// Run that transformation "over" your DataFrame
val afterTransformationDF = distinctValuesDF.select(myTransformationUDF(col("age")))
```

Answer (score 40):

In Pyspark try this,

`df.select('col_name').distinct().show()`

Comment: This works for scala too.

Answer (score 8):

This solution demonstrates how to transform data with Spark native functions which are better than UDFs.  It also demonstrates how `dropDuplicates` which is more suitable than `distinct` for certain queries.

Suppose you have this DataFrame:

```
+-------+-------------+
|country|    continent|
+-------+-------------+
|  china|         asia|
| brazil|south america|
| france|       europe|
|  china|         asia|
+-------+-------------+
```

Here's how to take all the distinct countries and run a transformation:

```scala
df
  .select("country")
  .distinct
  .withColumn("country", concat(col("country"), lit(" is fun!")))
  .show()
```

```
+--------------+
|       country|
+--------------+
|brazil is fun!|
|france is fun!|
| china is fun!|
+--------------+
```

You can use `dropDuplicates` instead of `distinct` if you don't want to lose the `continent` information:

```scala
df
  .dropDuplicates("country")
  .withColumn("description", concat(col("country"), lit(" is a country in "), col("continent")))
  .show(false)
```

```
+-------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|country|continent    |description                         |
+-------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|brazil |south america|brazil is a country in south america|
|france |europe       |france is a country in europe       |
|china  |asia         |china is a country in asia          |
+-------+-------------+------------------------------------+
```

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/filter-where/) for more information about filtering DataFrames and [here for more information on dropping duplicates](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/deduplicating-and-collapsing/).

Ultimately, you'll want to wrap your transformation logic in custom transformations that can be chained with the Dataset#transform method.

Comment: dropDuplicates allows you to maintain all the column information that are in dataframe but perform distinct on the column that is specified to the dropduplicates command.

Answer (score 1):

```
df =  df.select("column1", "column2",....,..,"column N").distinct.[].collect()
```

in the empty list, you can insert values like [ to_JSON()] if you want the df in a JSON format.